# How to change the center of a circle in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo, geometry

This time I'm struggling with changing the center of a circle in netlogo.
I have tried using layout-circle and create-ordered-turtle but I can't make the circle choose an other coordinate except the middle one.

```
to setup-food
  set-default-shape turtles "dot"

repeat num-food
  [patch-at random-pxcor random-pycor [cro 10 [fd radius set color blue]]]

 ;that was my first attempt
 ;now for the second one  

layout-circle turtles radius 
repeat num-food 
[ setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
  foreach range 25 [y -> ask turtle y
[ foreach range (24 - y) [x -> create-link-with turtle (x + (1 + y))]]]
 ]
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `create-ordered-turtles`, you can do:

```
to setup-food
  set-default-shape turtles "dot"
  repeat num-food [
    let center one-of patches
    cro 10 [
      move-to center
      fd radius
      set color blue
    ]
  ]
end
```

That is, you need to make sure you're moving all of the turtles to the same place. In your code, they were all going to different random patches before moving.